# Is there a formula for calculating Heuristic for "Map of Romania" problem?

Tags: python, algorithm, a-star

I'm learning A* search in Python, and my current problem is the well known "Map of Romania". The goal of this problem is to get from Arad to Bucharest, using the A* search. 
[This is what the graph looks like, with straight-line distance to the goal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ebbT.png) I'm trying to implement this in python and I don't know how is heuristic (in this example, location) calculated. This is what the "main" code looks like and the heuristic. Can anyone explain me how is `romania.locations` calculated? The code is taken from [here](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/python/search.html)

````
def h(self, node):
        "h function is straight-line distance from a node's state to goal."
        locs = getattr(self.graph, 'locations', None)
        if locs:
            return int(distance(locs[node.state], locs[self.goal]))
        else:
            return infinity
.
.
.
romania = UndirectedGraph(Dict(
    A=Dict(Z=75, S=140, T=118),
    B=Dict(U=85, P=101, G=90, F=211),
    C=Dict(D=120, R=146, P=138),
    D=Dict(M=75),
    E=Dict(H=86),
    F=Dict(S=99),
    H=Dict(U=98),
    I=Dict(V=92, N=87),
    L=Dict(T=111, M=70),
    O=Dict(Z=71, S=151),
    P=Dict(R=97),
    R=Dict(S=80),
    U=Dict(V=142)))
romania.locations = Dict(
    A=( 91, 492),    B=(400, 327),    C=(253, 288),   D=(165, 299),
    E=(562, 293),    F=(305, 449),    G=(375, 270),   H=(534, 350),
    I=(473, 506),    L=(165, 379),    M=(168, 339),   N=(406, 537),
    O=(131, 571),    P=(320, 368),    R=(233, 410),   S=(207, 457),
    T=( 94, 410),    U=(456, 350),    V=(509, 444),   Z=(108, 531))```
````

Comment: The locations seem to be an input here. The map you showed has a different kind of input (distances to Bucharest).